# Block access to Mysql Table inside Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, privileges

I have a website and a mysql db with 5 tables. One of them includes around 500 user emails. I am outsourcing the development of new features and I would like to block the access to the developer to the table that includes the user emails. The developer will have access to the whole database because he needs to add new tables, but I would like to stop him from accessing the user emails table.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780637/how-can-i-restrict-a-mysql-user-to-a-particular-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html)/[REVOKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/revoke.html) statements to limit the access right to some tables based on the user that is connected.

You will probably have to [create a new user](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html) in your DB an `REVOKE` the unnecessary rights on the table(s) you want to lock for that user.

Here is the full list of privileges supported by MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html#grant-privileges

Answer (score 0):

use `REVOKE` Priveleges to that user http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/revoke.html

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.emails FROM 'user'@'host';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there isn't a way you can restrict user to access some tables but you can restrict him to use only insert and update commands and not select command

```
CREATE USER 'test_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON `secure_login`.* TO 'test_user'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to copy your application to a development environment, replacing the emails with loremipsum.  This is the professional (and only reliable) way of fixing this problem.  It also allows scaling.

Otherwise, just get over it and make sure you have a strict non-disclosure agreement.