# How can I allow SQL Injection safely

Tags: sql, sql-injection

So I wanted to know if there is an acceptable method to Allow SQL Injection.

Example:

Limit permissions on the table(s)/database(s)

Why you ask?

My employer wanted to devise a way to test the skills of applicants, one suggestion was to allow resume submissions via SQL Injection.

Any thoughts? suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I think your boss needs to leave the technical stuff to the professionals.

Comment: Dont take me wrong but people are looking for ways to prevent SQL injection and your boss is looking for ways to have it! Strange :)

Comment: What an interesting company you work for. I guess isolated instance with limited roles should do the trick

Comment: it's just an idea, something outside the norm that you would need the know how to execute.

Comment: Does this help:- http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/videos/ethical-hacking-sql-injection-attack-advantages ?

Comment: Sanitise it, run in a sandbox (copy db), the  get the 'answer' out of it, or my favourite, test sql skills some more useful way.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter yes and yes! An Isolated instance that is no way related to anything we actually work on or use, hosted outside ( https://postgres.heroku.com/ perhaps ), what roles would you define?

Comment: What is currently preventing it?

Comment: @RahulTripathi I like the link as it does provide some insight on things, just not sure if what we want to do can be done

Comment: @PhillPafford:- Truly speaking I was also searching on Google to find out any but this was only one thing which I got. Still thinking and searching but I dont thing I could end up getting many! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use roles. Create a role for the web application (or whatever) that is used to connect to the database. Limit this role to only permit `INSERT` and access to necessary tables for applying. Applicants with access to your database through the application could then only use SQL injections to add their resume.

It may be possible for someone more talented in SQL to use injections in a way that increases the role's permission. But I think if the role had limited access to only specific tables and didn't have `CREATE` or `GRANT` privileges, the user wouldn't be able to create new roles.

Here is some information on roles to get you started:

[Adding Roles to MySQL with MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-adding-roles.html)

[Creating Roles in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createrole.html)

[`GRANT` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-grant.html) - used to add privileges to users on table, database, etc. This page is for PostgreSQL, but MySQL is very similar (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780637/how-can-i-restrict-a-mysql-user-to-a-particular-tables))

Comment: wouldn't applicants just be able to INSERT their resumes without the need on SQL injection?

Comment: If you just have a form for applicants to enter a name & email to be alerted when positions are posted. No direct way to upload resume, but the form provides contact to the db. Then similar to the comic, you might put `Matt'); INSERT resume...` in the name field. 
I'm not really clear what you have set up for them to use or what instructions are given.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just have a separate database for the applicants to inject their information. Applicants can circumvent the initial limited access and do as much damage as they want without your employer losing any of the information they need.
Then have a script saving the information elsewhere (so one applicant doesn't remove other resumes), and reset the database privileges to their initial limited access.

Comment: Thanks, I like the approach of limiting the input fields

Answer (score -1):

Given that the reason behind this is to test people's ability, create a database with data you can afford to lose.  Set up a form that posts to a coldfusion or php or java or .net or some other type of page which connects to that database.

On the form, put a textarea and submit button.  On the form target page, log what they put in the textarea.  Compare the log to the database to see how it turned out.

Then test to your heart's delight.