# Restrict db_user to single db_table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database named vendzvtq_accounts with a table named "netflix":
In the database user vendzvtq_username has SELECT privileges.

I need to restrict vendzvtq_username so that he can only access the netflix table, i'll later add 2 other users and restrict them to manage other tables, but it will be always 1 table per user.

I searched and found this previous question 
[How can I restrict a MySQL user to a particular tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780637/how-can-i-restrict-a-mysql-user-to-a-particular-tables) which seemed exactly what i was looking for, so i executed the query:

```
GRANT SELECT ON vendzvtq_accounts.netflix TO vendzvtq_username@'%'
```

And got this error (cannot post images):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBfIw.png

So i searched for error #1142 and this has been the result: [MySQL Error: #1142 - SELECT command denied to user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956195/mysql-error-1142-select-command-denied-to-user)

But user has already the SELECT privilege in my database:
http://i.gyazo.com/7af43ad6f8718a31dae3bb0a040568ac.png

so what should i do?

Comment: With what user (what administrative user) are you attempting to issue the `GRANT SELECT ...` command? The error message you received tells us that administrative user doesn't have the authority to issue `GRANT` commands.

Comment: I guess it is always vendzvtq_username, it's the only user which has permissions inside the database: http://i.imgur.com/S6MWfRg.png

I also connect to the database via the phpmyadmin link inside my hoster's control panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [#1142 error message says MySQL has denied](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_tableaccess_denied_error) the `GRANT SELECT...` request, because the user trying to do that doesn't have the authority to do so.   (The StackOverflow page you found is not relevant to your situation, because it's about a failure to SELECT, not GRANT).

The database user with which you,  manually, or your application issues the `GRANT SELECT ...` request needs to have `GRANT` privilege, at a minimum on the database (schema) containing the table you mention.

Applications like this require at least two different usernames to work properly.  It doesn't make sense to try to do this with just one username.

One is the manager user, from which operations like access granting and table creation are performed. That user needs privs like `GRANT` and `CREATE` as well as `SELECT`.

The other (of which there might be many) is the restricted-access user -- the one to whom access is granted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so what should i do to add more privileges to the manager user with which i access the database, in order to restrict vendzvtq_username in vendzvtq_accounts?
Checking in information_schema 
http://i.gyazo.com/b77465de9ffd3a539b640ea481a3e8ad.png
I found this table http://gyazo.com/ab14e80e75961f8332122984fe8ae746 but still don't know how to improve privileges

Comment: Ask your hosting service provider for help with this. Usually there's some interface in the control panel for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot, hopefully will sort this out!