# How should i provide security for a schema(mysql)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have the table with username and password named 'credentials' table and 'role' table having roles of organization.I want to grant permission to that schema depending on the roles present in the table 'role' of that schema.

what i need to do?

Comment: programatically grant a user rights on a table, based on data from another table - note you must hold a "superuser" to act as a giver / taker for this cases.. check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780637/how-can-i-restrict-a-mysql-user-to-a-particular-tables

Comment: programatically..does it mean by using the application

Comment: yes- I think you need an application on top of your db in order to do that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not let anyone or any application have write or even read access to the `mysql` database.  Exception:  the Admin, who preferably has access only from localhost.

This implies `GRANT ... ON dbname.* TO ...` is the most that you give do non-admins.  (Where `dbname` is not `mysql`.)

If the application (especially a web application) gets compromised, the hacker can see whatever data that it was `GRANTed`.  If that includes `mysql`, then he can fish around to for the `root` password and do other nasties.

I have seen such a security flaw come in via a web page, and get the unix password file!.

local_infile = ON is also a security hole waiting to be exploited.  Turning it off puts a crimp in certain load mechanisms, but it is worth it for an exposed web site.